# Twilio round robin not stopping when someone answers

Tags: twilio

Can you tell me if it is possible to forward an incoming call to a list of multiple numbers, so when one  timeouts another starts?

What I am trying to do is basically this:

```
<Dial timeout="10">+123</Dial>
<Dial timeout="10">+124</Dial>
<Dial timeout="10">+124</Dial>
```

Now Dial 1 for +123 times out, but Dial 2 for +124 get's answered, so I do NOT want to start Dial 3 but it calls 3 after 2 answered. How would I achieve that? I'm basically trying to make it so multiple numbers are being called but in a sequence and the sequence stops if one answers.  If you have an alternative to just using simple  I'm open for that too.

Thank you.

Comment: You should show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way to do this without continuing to call once someone answers is by separating the `<Dial>`s into different webhooks. You'd do so by providing an [`action` attribute to the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) which is a URL that will be called when the `<Dial>` is completed.

That way you can use the [`DialCallStatus` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-parameters) that is sent to the `action` URL to see whether the phone was answered or not. If it was answered, then you can just return [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/hangup) if it wasn't answered, you can `<Dial>` the next number in your list.

You can also use the [FindMe Twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme) for this purpose or [this code written for Twilio Functions](https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/tree/master/hunt).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: No problem! If this has helped, could you mark the answer as the solution so that it may help others too? Thanks!